# WebServices giving errors when accessed directly from the browser

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5, asmx

I have the following web-service which works perfectly as long as it is accessed from a clientside script (javascript, jquery)

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" Class="WebService" %>

Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Services

<ScriptService()> _
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Public Class Person
        Public FirstName As String
        Public LastName As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal m_FirstName As String, ByVal m_LastName As String)
            FirstName = m_FirstName
            LastName = m_LastName
        End Sub
    End Class

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetPersons() As List(Of Person)
        Dim People As List(Of Person) = New List(Of Person)

        People.Add(New Person("firstname_1", "surname_1"))
        People.Add(New Person("firstname_2", "surname_2"))

        Return People
    End Function
End Class
```

But for some reason it gives me errors if I try to access it directly in the browser

```
http://localhost/webservices/WebService.asmx
http://localhost/webservices/WebService.asmx/GetPersons
```

to see the standard web-service service description showing all the operations supported

The error I get is:

```
WebService.Person cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.
```

Comment: why not adding a parameter-less constructor then?

Comment: I doubt I would have posted this question if I knew what that was all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parameterless constructor for your  Person

```
  Public Class Person
        Public FirstName As String
        Public LastName As String

        Public Sub New()
          'just add this constructor  
        End Sub
    End Class
```